# center a div without using position

Tags: css

Second div should be aligned in center without using position and first and last div has float

```
 <div class="abc">
    </div>
    <div class="def">
    </div>
    <div class="ghi">
    </div>
```

Comment: `.def { float: left;}` or better `div{float : left}`

Comment: A plunker would help as to what has been accomplished so far

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What is the _real_ issue? How come you can't use `position`? Let's solve that one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using float on `first` and `last`. It will not work, the last div fill go down. You can use flex for that.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}
.container div{
  flex: 1;
}
.abc{
  text-align: left
}
.ghi{
  text-align: right;
}
.def{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="abc">
   1st
 </div>
 <div class="def">
  second
 </div>
 <div class="ghi">
  third
 </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vLearbz6/) here

Comment: Note that the middle div is not *actually* centered unless the left/right divs **are the same size**.